# Vector bundle vs Total Space

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

On page 59 in Lee's "An Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" the author writes,

"Let $E$ be a smooth vector bundle over a smooth manifold $M$, with projection $\pi:E\to M$."

I thought the vector bundle in this case would be $\left(E,M,\pi\right)$, making $E$ the total space rather than the vector bundle, or am I wrong?

Comment: There is actually no such statement on page 59 in my book, in either the first or second edition.  You must be using one of the pirated draft versions of the first edition, which somebody posted illegally on the internet. Those are full of mistakes and come with no guarantees.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right; this is just a common abuse of terminology.  This is similar to how we frequently talk about a "group $G$" (when the group is really the pair $(G,\cdot)$) or a "topological space $X$" (when the topological space is really the pair $(X,T)$, where $T$ is a topology on $X$).

(Actually, it is not even accurate to say that the vector bundle is $(E,M,\pi)$, since you also have to specify the vector space structure on each fiber.)

Comment: So strictly speaking, apart from defining the vector space operations, the tangent bundle is actually $\left(TM,M,\pi\right)$ (where $\pi\left(p,v\right)=p$) rather than $TM$? Similarly, whenever $TM$ is referred to as the tangent bundle, it is shorthand for $\left(TM,M,\pi\right)$?

Comment: Yes.  But you will almost never see anyone bother to write this out, just like you will almost never see someone explicitly write a group or topological space as a pair, or for that matter a smooth manifold as a pair including an atlas.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect answer. On page 250 of _ISM_ (2nd edition), just after the definition of a vector bundle, I wrote "Depending on what we wish to emphasize, we sometimes omit some of the ingredients from the notation, and write '$E$ is a vector bundle over $M$,' or '$E\to M$ is a vector bundle,' or $\pi\colon E\to M$ is a vector bundle."